# Javascript switch shape of an existing shape

Tags: javascript, shapes

i have a project in javascript which is about a square that is moving using the keyboard ( up, down, right , left) now i want to be able to change the shape of the square into a triangle or a circle for example. I want to do this by pressing for example 1 and change the shape into a circle, 2 and change the shape into a triangle. At the same time i want the new shape to be able to move using up, down,left,right

The question is, How can i change the shape of my square into a triangle? or a circle?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactiune cu tastatura</title>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="patrat"></div>
<div id="triangle"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#patrat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}


#triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}


#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

main.js

```
    var step = 100,
        squareLeft = 0,
        squareTop = 0,
        squareSide = 100,
        triangleLeft = 0,
        triangleTop = 0,
        triangleSide = 100,
        circleLeft = 0,
        circleTop = 0,
        circleSide = 0,
        screenWidth = 1920,
        screenHeight = 1080;


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)
    {

    var keyCode = event.keyCode,
        spaceLeft = 0,
        x = document.getElementById("patrat");
        y = document.getElementById("triangle");



    switch (keyCode) {
    case(49):
    document.getElementById("circle");

    case (13):  /*ENTER*/
        /*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Text test";*/
        /*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.style.backgroundColor;*/
            x.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,0)";
    break;

    case (37):  /*ArrowLeft*/
        if (squareLeft > 0) {
        squareLeft = (squareLeft > step) ? squareLeft - step : 0;
        x.style.left = squareLeft + "px";
        }
    break;

    case (39):  /*ArrowRight*/
        spaceLeft = screenWidth - squareLeft - squareSide;
        if (spaceLeft > 0) {
            squareLeft += (spaceLeft > step) ? step : spaceLeft;
            x.style.left = squareLeft + "px";       
        }
    break;

    case (38):  /*ArrowUp*/
        if (squareTop > 0) {
            squareTop = (squareTop > step) ? squareTop - step : 0;
            x.style.top = squareTop + "px";
        }
        break;

    case (40): /*ArrowDown*/
        spaceLeft = screenHeight - squareTop - squareSide;
        if (spaceLeft > 0) {
        squareTop += (spaceLeft > step) ? step : spaceLeft;
        x.style.top = squareTop + "px";
                }
    break;

    default:
    alert("Aceasta tasta nu este utilizata");
    break;

    }
    }
);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i change the shape of the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your triangle CSS class is correct, it looks like you could start by changing the ID of the element:

```
document.getElementById('circle').id = 'triangle';
```

...but this architecture is brittle and not recommended. A step down the road to improvement would be use classnames:

```
document.querySelector('.circle').className = 'triangle';
```

which will turn the first DOM element with a class of `circle` into a triangle. Your CSS will look like

```
.circle {
    ...
}

.triangle {
    ...
}
```

To turn all `.circle`s into `.triangle`s, do something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.circle').forEach(function(element) {
    element.className = triangle;
});
```

Again, this is assuming your CSS classes are rendering the shapes as expected.

Comment: it woked but now i got another problem, the new item doesn't get the movement function. I mean for example when i switch from square to triangle the triangle doesn't move with the keyboard.

Comment: @DanMihai great! The movement will be a separate question but obviously something in your keydown handler.  I know it sounds crazy, but I'd recommend you start over rather than debug - you've learned a lot, and the second time you'll go a lot faster, with less mistakes, and be able to find where the movement problem is probably coming from. Welcome to SO and good luck!